Boundary conditions for stratified thermal storage model with variable in- and outlet positions
I am working on a stratified thermal storage model for a vertical tank and I am having trouble defining the boundary conditions for the edge cells.
All the models I could find online have the inlet at the bottom cell and define the boundary using the inlet flow. For my case I need to model the tank so that the inlet can be anywhere. Usually the boundary cells are constrained by 0 mass and heat flow, but in my case, with a forward discretization and no external mass flow, the bottom cells remain unchanged because they don't interact with the rest of the fluid, only ambient losses affect them.
Is there any workaround for this? Should I somehow change the differentiation scheme?

Why would th init be "anywhere"? The inlet should be placed to ensure minimum disruption of the stratification.

@SolarMike Yes, I get that that's usually the case but the goal here is to have a storage where multiple in- and outlets could be connected and some of them being at different heights. It's supposed to be quite a flexible system.

So what how many? and at what height. If you use thermostatic valves to control output temperature that can be effective.

There's not really a set number or height. It should be made so the number and height could be changed based on the case.

So if you want cold then take from the bottom, hot take from the top...

That is reasonable usually, however here the goal isn't to just simulate a thermal storage connected to something, but to observe a bit more the behavior of the flow and temperature inside the storage in different cases.

So let the tank stabilise and then add some warm water which has some colour in it. Film where it goes, add slowly so as to minimise the movement. Repeat as needed.
